# Accessing Shell variable from within Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying the below line in my Jenkins Pipeline. In the below set of lines, I am assigning the variable `IMAGE_NAME` in a shell, and trying to access that in the Jenkins Pipeline script, but not able to do that. Any idea on how to do that?

```
stage('Build: Get Image') {
    steps {
        echo 'Getting docker image'
        sh "IMAGE_NAME=`grep -ri \"Successfully built\" 
            $BUILD_FILE_NAME | awk \'{print \$3}\'`"
        echo "Image Name is:$IMAGE_NAME"
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether the global environment variables are exposed to jenkins or not, depend pretty much on how you start jenkins and how those variables are defined. 

Issue the command "env" inside jenkins step to see which variables are available. 


Also how do you start jenkins and how/where do you define this variable??

Comment: I did an env but it was not showing IMAGE_NAME. But today after lot of struggle i found out the issue. There was a \r\n character at the end of the IMAGE_NAME data. so I used to strip off \r\n with the following command, with printf inside the awk and it worked fine. Thank you so much

sh "IMAGE_NAME=`grep -ri \"Successfully built\" 
            $BUILD_FILE_NAME | awk \'{printf \"%s\" \$3}\'`"

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as env variable:

```
env.some_var = 'AAAA'
```

And print with:

```
sh 'echo ${env.some_var}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy_host = 'abc.com'
stage('Docker Up') {
steps{
script{
sh("""                
echo ${http_proxy}
""")
}
```

}

Catch here is to use double quotes " to execute the shell script. I tested it and it works fine.